# How does Parse pick which Mongo index to use?

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, mongodb-query, parse-server

I just inherited a Parse project that uses Mongo, so I'm doing a bunch of research into Mongo and indexes.

I log into MLab and notice that there are a bunch of indexes that were written by engineers before me, many of them seemingly redundant.

**So a few questions:**

1. How does Parse (or Mongo) pick which index to use to make the query most efficient (and should I remove a bunch of these, as they seem redundant)?
2. I've created the index that I'm pointing to in the image below named `keywordIndexedListings`. Is there a way to specifically search with that named index? I haven't found anything in the docs that says I can.

[image]

Comment: If this is an older Parse project that used the hosted Parse.com, many of these indexes were likely actually auto-generated by Parse. This feature was removed when users were required to take over their own database management back in... August 2016 ish? It would auto generate indexes based on the Parse queries you would run, and often create redundant ones. I.e., if you have {"id":1,"_wperm":1}, you do not need {"_id":1}, as it's already covered by the former. It is good to delete redundant ones because they needlessly slow down database writes.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: I don't know of a way to make Parse choose an index, but you should use Mongo's `explain()` feature to measure index performance and usage, and then delete suboptimal ones that are being used heavily. Also, utilize MLab's great support team for specific optimization questions.

As far as I know, there's no way to do a Mongo `hint()` with Parse.

Instead, you need to run `explain()` on your queries and see which indexes are being used. If your query is using a suboptimal index, then I don't think there's much you can do but delete it.

Here's some info on [measuring index use](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/measure-index-use/), but the tricky part is transforming your parse queries to mongo queries so you can test them.

The easiest way I've found is to use the [beforeFind](http://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#beforefind-triggers) trigger in cloud code. When I'm trying to translate a query, `console.log()` it here, and then transcribing it to a mongo query is usually pretty straightforward.

After you have the mongo query, you can run explains on it and see which indexes are being utilized, and that can inform your decisions on which indexes to remove/keep.

Other than keeping a clean ship with your indexes (i.e. not having suboptimal/redundant ones), I'm not sure there's much you can do to ensure the correct one is being used. Also, if you've got a paid MLab plan, their support is very helpful and can help dig into the specifics of your DB performance and give you tips on how to optimize your indexes. Be sure to reach out to them with specific index questions-- they've helped me tremendously in the past.

Comment: Awesome tip on the beforeFind! Wish I knew that one earlier!

Comment: @JakeT. beforeFind is also incredibly useful for supporting outdated clients (i.e. iOS app) that may be using queries that you want to change. In the beforeFind, you can intercept the query, modify it, and then return the query you actually want to use. It's great to use when you're in the process of refactoring/optimizing queries

Comment: Now that's a pro tip! Is there an easy way to assign identifiers to the queries to know the intent behind it or anything? Or do you have to just check all of the constraints to determine that a bit more "manually"?

Comment: @JakeT. Hmm sorry, I don't know of a good way to do that, but if you're not doing it all the time, then it shouldn't be too hard to manually define some query shapes, and then check to see if the incoming query matches one of them

Comment: How do I do `explain()` with `PFQuery`? I can't seem to find anything on that

Comment: @ZackShapiro you can't, you have to translate the PFQuery to a mongo query, which is usually pretty easy, or you can just observe your mongo logs and get the query from there. It would be really nice if Parse had a way to display the query after it's been converted to a mongo query!

Comment: Thanks Lulzcow. Am I correct to translate this simply query into the following mongo query?

```
PFQuery *buyingUnseenQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"convos"];
[buyingUnseenQuery whereKey:@"buyerUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[buyingUnseenQuery whereKey:@"buyerDeleted" equalTo:@"NO"];       
[buyingUnseenQuery whereKey:@"buyerUnseen" greaterThan:@0]; 

db.convos.find { buyerUser: "abc", buyerDeleted: "NO", buyerUnseen: { "$gt": 0 } }```

Comment: @ZackShapiro Looks ok, but there is one tricky part with pointers. Just make sure that any part of your mongo query that uses pointers looks like this `buyerUser: "_p_User$objectId"`. And I'm not sure about Objc, but I'm assuming `"NO"` is a string and not a boolean?

Comment: We have bools as strings currently. They're gross. I'm changing that :)

I'm assuming that Parse knows how to correctly do that pointer in the `[buyerConvos whereKey:@"buyerUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];` line

Comment: Right, Parse converts it automatically, but when you're writing mongo queries, pointers and a couple of other fields are named slightly differently